# Is there a simple way to create a composer.json in Typo3 (already composer installation)

Tags: json, composer-php, typo3

i took on a project from a customer, that has the following setup:

- a Typo3 V10.4.12 (already a composer installation)
- there are already extensions installed
- no extension manager in the Typo3 backend

So the problem is:
I need to install some additional extensions (blog, mask).
But there is no (main) composer.json file in the project. I don´t know what happened (maybe deleted by the former developer by mistake?). There is no backup of the file etc.

Is there a way to automatically generate a composer.json?

Or do i have to write it by my own?

Comment: Why not create one? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The problem is: i´m unsure what to include in a new composer.json file. I know the typo3conf extensions, but not really what is also needed for this installation. What if i run the comman composer install and because of missing entries the typo3-installation will be broken?

Comment: @Harleqeen247: Then you revert the composer.json configuration. It's hard to reason about unknown problems technically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [EXT:migrate2composer](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/migrate2composer), maybe it can help you.

To configure/change the installation, maybe the CLI could help you if you have a working shell:

In a composer installation execute:

```
./vendor/bin/typo3
```

In a non-composer installation execute:

```
php ./typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3
```

There's also a tutorial "[Migrate TYPO3 Project to Composer](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/MigrateToComposer/Index.html)" as part of the official docs, but this seems to match your case.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. The extension [migrate2composer](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/migrate2composer) worked (at least on a local dev environment).

I did the following:

1. Deactivate composer mode (in vendor/typo3/autoload-include.php)
2. Install migrate2composer via extension manager
3. Run command from extension migrate2composer to print and show all "composer-errors" -> result was the required composer.json
4. Add the new composer.json and reactivate composer mode
5. Installed the required extensions via composer

Regards